# GLFW3 not cooperating with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, glfw

So I've been trying for weeks to get GLFW3 to work with MinGW (via Code::Blocks IDE) and it fails every time. I'm getting handfulls of "undefined references" with every single glfw argument. Could someone walk me through how to set that up from scratch? the readme that came with glfw was not very helpful and fixed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not do it already, try if Version 3.0.3 of GLFW3 works. They have had trouble with
"legacy" MinGW in earlier versions. If everything else fails, http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net  seems to be a more up-to-date fork of the MinGW toolchain for windows - with mingw-w64, I had no trouble with GLFW3.